# In place of a failable initializer, can you instead have it return a default case?

Tags: swift, enums, swift4, failable

Consider this enum...

```
enum ServiceValue : String, Decodable {
    case a
    case b
    case c
    case other
}
```

Given a string 'a' you can get an instance of the enum, like so:

```
// 'value' is an optional since the initializer is bailable
let value = ServiceValue(rawValue:'a')
```

What we're trying to do is instead of returning 'nil' for unknown values such as 'd' or 'somethingUnknown', we want to return `ServiceValue.other`. However you can't override the initializer since it's not in a base-class, but rather compiler-generated for this enumeration itself.

That said, we tried rolling our own, like so...

```
init(serviceValue:String){
    self.init(rawValue:serviceValue) ?? self.init(rawValue:"other")
}
```

...but that didn't work with the following errors:

> A non-failable initializer cannot delegate to failable initializer 'init(rawValue:)' written with 'init?'

and

> Initializer delegation ('self.init') cannot be nested in another expression

Of course I could simply write a static method `initFrom`, like so...

```
initFrom(serviceValue:String) -> ServiceValue {
    return ServiceValue(rawValue:serviceValue) ?? ServiceValue(rawValue:"other")
}
```

...but that's a factory method, not a true initializer, nor does it protect against someone still using `init(rawValue:` (although perhaps that last part is good as it would be changing expected behavior. In a perfect world, I'd just hide that initializer altogether, but again, you can't override initializers in an enum.)

So can this be achieved, or is the factory pattern the only way to go?

Comment: `init(string: String) {
        self = ServiceValue(rawValue: string) ?? .other
    }`

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding something, I'm not sure that's the same thing because that's about initializing *properties* on the object.  In the case of the enum, it's the object *itself* I'm trying to default. (I wish I could see the guts of what the compiler generates so I could replicate it, still as an init, but with a different signature.)

Comment: Leo, can you put that in an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create your custom non fallible initializer with a default value as follow:

```
init(string: String) { 
    self = ServiceValue(rawValue: string) ?? .other
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity do you know why does calling the initializer using the type name work while doing `self.init(rawValue:)` doesn't?

Comment: @DávidPásztor I guess it is a limitation for using the nil coalescing operator that requires both types to be the same and btw self.init(rawValue:) is a fallible initializer but doesn't return any value so using the nil coalescing operator there doesn't make any sense

Comment: It was the `self.init` vs `ServiceValue.init` that was the solution. Your explanation of how `self.init` doesn't return anything whereas `ServiceValue.init` does helped explain this much better.  That and being able to assign `self` which I didn't think was possible, but apparently is.